# C# Entity Framework: creating one-to-many relationship

Tags: c#, entity-framework, relational-database

This issue has been driving me nuts for days, and frankly at the moment I feel like I'm clueless because I've been searching for so long and tried so many things and none of them work. So I thought it would be time to ask a question.

I'm trying to create a small console app that works with workout moves (Move) as primary entity. However, as part of the app I also want users to be able leave a rating and intensity for each workout in an entity called MoveRating which collects mentioned ratings whenever a Move is fetched.

So this lead me to create the following set-up:

**Move.cs**

```
    public class Move
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string MoveName { get; set; }
        public string MoveDescription { get; set; }
        public int SweatRate { get; set; }
        public ICollection<MoveRating> MoveRating { get; set; }
    }
```

**MoveRating.cs**

```
    public class MoveRating
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public Move Move { get; set; }
        public double Rating { get; set; }
        public double Intensity { get; set; }
    }
```

Now I know I'm supposed to do something in my DbContext to make this happen, I've been trying stuff like the following:

**DbContext (only the OnModelCreating part)**

```
      protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
          {
            builder.Entity<MoveRating>().HasOne(m => m.Move).WithMany(a => a.MoveRating);
            builder.Entity<Move>().HasMany(m => m.MoveRating).WithOne(g => g.Move);
          }
```

I know it shouldn't be like this, but whatever example I do try to follow it just doesn't work. I've tried stuff like:

```
    builder.Entity<MoveRating>().HasOne(b => b.Move).WithMany(m => m.MoveRating).HasForeignKey(m => m.MoveId);
```

Or

```
    builder.Entity<Move>().HasMany(m => m.MoveRating).WithRequired(m => m.MoveRating);
```

I feel like one of these should work. But whatever I try to do I can't seem to get it to work. It will give me messages like "MoveRating does not contain a definition for MoveId" or "CollectionNavigationBuilder<Move, MoveRating> does nto contain a definition for WithRequired."

Can someone please help me get over this issue? I'm losing my mind.

Comment: You can do this with convention, instead of fluent api. 

Move can have many ratings, so you can just add a virtual list of ratings as a property in move. Create DbSet properties in your context and ef takes care of the rest. I’m on my phone but if someone else hasn’t answered, I’ll write one for you later from the computer.

Comment: @nico_c Do you mean like this?  `class MoveContext : DbContext
     {
          public DbSet<Move> Move { get; set; }
          public DbSet<MoveRating> MoveRating { get; set; } ` 

because else I wouldn't know what you mean exactly. Sadly this doesn't work

Comment: I’ll write an answer for you later with an example if no one else does. Are you on ef or ef core?

Comment: I'm using EF Core, thanks a bunch for being willing to help out. It's very much appreciated.

Comment: Added details for you in the answer. my recommendation is to create a new application as I explain in the answer as it is possible you don't have all of the tools/libraries installed and/or referenced.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new directory, call it whatever you want.

Inside the directory, create a new `mvc` application with the following command on the command line:

```
dotnet new mvc --auth Individual
```

`--auth Individual` part ensures you have `entity framework` libraries referenced.

Open your application code in your text editor.

To create a one to many relationship in EF Core with one Move to many MoveRatings, your entities would look like this (notice the `[Key]` annotation):

```
public class Move
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string MoveName { get; set; }
    public string MoveDescription { get; set; }
    public int SweatRate { get; set; }
    public List<MoveRating> MoveRating { get; set; }
}

public class MoveRating
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Move Move { get; set; }
    public double Rating { get; set; }
    public double Intensity { get; set; }
}
```

In your DbContext, you will have two properties like so:

```
public DbSet<Move> Moves { get; set; }
public DbSet<MoveRating> MoveRatings { get; set; }
```

Make sure your `ConnectionString` is pointing to the correct server and database. You will find this string, in most cases, in `appsettings.js`.

Once everything looks good, you will execute the following in the command line (make sure you're inside your project directory):

```
dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate
```

When that runs successfully, you can see a Migrations folder and there you will see a file with a name that starts with some numbers followed by InitialCreate.cs. You can open it and see that it looks something like this:

```
protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
{
    migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
        name: "Moves",
        columns: table => new
        {
            Id = table.Column<int>(type: "INTEGER", nullable: false)
                .Annotation("Sqlite:Autoincrement", true),
            MoveName = table.Column<string>(type: "TEXT", nullable: true),
            MoveDescription = table.Column<string>(type: "TEXT", nullable: true),
            SweatRate = table.Column<int>(type: "INTEGER", nullable: false)
        },
        constraints: table =>
        {
            table.PrimaryKey("PK_Moves", x => x.Id);
        });

    migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
        name: "MoveRatings",
        columns: table => new
        {
            Id = table.Column<int>(type: "INTEGER", nullable: false)
                .Annotation("Sqlite:Autoincrement", true),
            MoveId = table.Column<int>(type: "INTEGER", nullable: true),
            Rating = table.Column<double>(type: "REAL", nullable: false),
            Intensity = table.Column<double>(type: "REAL", nullable: false)
        },
        constraints: table =>
        {
            table.PrimaryKey("PK_MoveRatings", x => x.Id);
            table.ForeignKey(
                name: "FK_MoveRatings_Moves_MoveId",
                column: x => x.MoveId,
                principalTable: "Moves",
                principalColumn: "Id",
                onDelete: ReferentialAction.Restrict);
        });

    migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
        name: "IX_MoveRatings_MoveId",
        table: "MoveRatings",
        column: "MoveId");
}
```

After you're happy, execute the following in the command line:

```
dotnet ef database update
```

That should create the relationship in your database.

**Notes**

If you don't have EF tools installed, you can install them by executing:

```
dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef
```

in your command line.

**References**

EF Core - Relationships: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key

EF Core - Tools Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/dotnet

Comment: Thank you for writing this out, this seems to work. However, could you also get it to work if you leave MoveRating as an ICollectable? My teacher seems to really want me to get it to work with that.

Comment: @borovanhout Nothing magical about `List` vs `ICollection` (there is no `ICollectable` type). Same result. Feel free to delete the Migrations folder in your test app, change the property from List to ICollection and run migrations again. You'll get the same result.

Comment: @borovanhout I am fairly certain you're missing libraries and/or references. After you create this example app, take a look at your .csproj file and make sure you have EF Core packages referenced the same way in your Console App as well.

Comment: Alright I'll take a more elaborate look at my references and packages tomorrow just to be sure, I'll keep you updated on if I find anything. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you to define all relations with the help of `ModelBuilder` as less as possible, because you need to check out your configuration file each time, when you to rewind your database structure. Still it's up to you.

Basically, what you need is just add an `int MoveId` property in `MoveRating` class, remove your config and that's all. It will fetch `Move` table because of names convention.

Comment: also take a look at this article https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/conventions/one-to-many-relationship

Comment: I tried to do this but it still doesn't fetch the `MoveRatings` when i query for a `Move`

Comment: You need to do a new migration if you already have one. You'd better stick with detailed answers, mine might be not that clear..

Answer (score 0):

If your database already exists and you are not using Code-first + migrations to update it, ensure that your MoveRating table has a MoveId column. It will need one.

Next: for your object definitions I recommend always declaring the navigation properties as `virtual`. This ensures that lazy loading will be available as a fall-back to avoid things like null reference exceptions. Collections should be auto-initialized so they are ready to go when creating new parent entities as well:

```
public class Move
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string MoveName { get; set; }
    public string MoveDescription { get; set; }
    public int SweatRate { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<MoveRating> MoveRating { get; set; } = new List<MoveRating>();
}

public class MoveRating
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Move Move { get; set; }
    public double Rating { get; set; }
    public double Intensity { get; set; }
}
```

Next will be mapping the association between Move and MoveRating. You could add a MoveId to your MoveRating entity to serve as the FK to Move:

```
public class MoveRating
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Move")]
    public int MoveId { get; set; }
    public virtual Move Move { get; set; }
    public double Rating { get; set; }
    public double Intensity { get; set; }
}
```

This is simple and should get you going, but I generally advise against doing this as it creates two sources of truth for the Move reference. (moveRating.MoveId and moveRating.Move.Id)  Updating the FK does not automatically update the reference to "Move" and vice-versa. YOu can leverage shadow properties to specify the FK without declaring the FK field in the entity. Given the error you got with `HasRequired` it looks like you are using EF Core:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    builder.Entity<Move>()
        .HasMany(m => m.MoveRating)
        .WithOne(g => g.Move)
        .HasForeignKey("MoveId");
}
```

This is where your MoveRating entity ***does not*** have a field for "MoveId" declared. EF will create a shadow property to represent the FK mapping behind the scenes.

When using modelBuilder or EntityTypeConfigurations, only map out relationships from one side, not both sides. For instance if you create a `HasMany` from Move to MoveRating, do not add another mapping from MoveRating back to Move. (It isn't required and it can lead to bugs)

Lastly, when reading your Move and it's associated MoveRatings collections, if you know you are going to need the ratings, eager load them when you read the Move entity. This generally means avoiding EF methods like `Find` in favour of Linq methods like `Single`.

```
var move = context.Moves
    .Include(m => m.MoveRatings)
    .Single(m => m.MoveId == moveId);
```

This would fetch the move /w it's collection of Ratings in one SQL call. By declaring the MoveRatings as `virtual` provides a safety net that if you forget to use Include on a Move, provided that its DbContext reference is still alive, the MoveRatings can be pulled with a lazy load call when accessed. (Something to watch out for and avoid whenever possible, but better than triggering a null reference exception)

Answer (score 0):

Took me a number of days, but the answer to the problem was stupidly simple...

It didn't take the MoveRatings because I tried to access them outside of the data access layer where I defined my DbContext.. That was all..

Don't know if I should keep this open for visisbility (since I couldn't find this answer anywhere) or if I should delete